# Modifying ListBox using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very new to VBA and I've been trying to find a way to create a date selection drop-down but I haven't been successful in handling a "February" selection. Here is what I have so far,

```
If (monthListBox.Value = "Jan" Or monthListBox.Value = "Mar" Or monthListBox.Value = "May" Or monthListBox.Value = "Jul" Or monthListBox.Value = "Aug" Or monthListBox.Value = "Oct" Or monthListBox.Value = "Dec") Then
    If dayCount < 31 Then
        For i = dayCount To 31
            dateComboBox.AddItem (i)
        Next i
    End If
ElseIf (monthListBox.Value = "Apr" Or monthListBox.Value = "Jun" Or monthListBox.Value = "Sep" Or monthListBox.Value = "Nov") Then
    dateComboBox.RemoveItem (30)
    If dayCount < 30 Then
        For i = dayCount To 30
            dateComboBox.AddItem (i)
        Next i
    End If
Else
    If isLeapYear = True Then
        With dateComboBox
            .RemoveItem (30)
            .RemoveItem (29)
        End With
    Else
        dateComboBox.RemoveItem (28)
    End If
End If
```

Comment: What exactly are you having troubles handling? What is the expected outcome and what outcome are tou getting?

Answer (score 1):

Try,

It would be easier for you to apply the calculated date system to the system than to calculate the leap year.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim i As Integer, s As String

    y = 2020 '<~~ your year

    For i = 1 To 12
        s = Format(DateSerial(y, i, 1), "mmm")
        monthListBox.AddItem s
    Next i

End Sub

Private Sub monthListBox_Click()
    Dim s  As String
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim st As Double, et As Double
    Dim i As Integer, cnt As Integer

    y = 2020 '<~~ your year

    s = monthListBox.Value
    st = DateValue(y & "/" & s & "/" & 1)
    et = DateAdd("m", 1, st)
    cnt = et - st

    dateComboBox.Clear
    For i = 1 To cnt
        dateComboBox.AddItem i
    Next i


End Sub
```

### Image

[image]

Comment: just to throw in that the list of months names is a built in function `MonthName()` so that the code inside the first loop can simply be `monthListBox.AddItem MonthName(i)` (or `monthListBox.AddItem Left$(MonthName(i),3)`, to keep first three letters only)

Comment: @HTH, In my country it is a different character. Anyway, thanks for the new function.

Comment: @HTH, In my country MonthName(1)   is "1월".